# Call Back Concept in Javascript

Tags: javascript

How Java script engine handles Callback and how does the engine know that it is a callback if we pass a function as a parameter to another function.

Comment: `typeof Callback == 'function'`. Functions implement the `call` method which distinguishes them from other objects.

Comment: Maybe they don't have to, you explicitly invoke the callback parameter `callback()`

Answer (score 1):

Oversimplifying, functions are something we can pass around, like anything else. We can pass parameters that are numbers, functions, strings, etc.

Take a look at this:

```
// We'll just call the function passed in our function
// This is essentially a callback that does no work before
// calling the callback.
function call_function(f) {
  return f();
}


var func = function(s) {console.log('func was called');}
var notAFunc = 42;


call_function(func);      // func was called
call_function(notAFunc);  // TypeError: number is not a function
```

The `TypeError` is the same as trying to call 42 as a function (because that's all we're doing):

```
42()  // TypeError: number is not a function
```

The basics are that JavaScript doesn't do anything extra special to know if a callback you're passing is a function or not. At some point it will try to call the function, which may or may not result in an error.

### EDIT

Xufox noted in a comment that the type of the paramenter could be checked, something like this:

```
function call_function(f) {
  if (typeof f === 'function') {
    return f();
  }
}
```

It's good to keep that in mind, but that has nothing to do with the *engine*, it's up to the programmer to do that kind of sanity checking.